# magento2 : How to copy a file programmatically in Controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, file

I have a controller execute() function in which I would like to make a file copy from a directory to another.

In Magento 1.9 I was using :

```
Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->copyFile($_OriginalPath, $_NewPath);
```

How to perform that in Magento2?

Edit 3:

I tried :

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    protected $_FileDB;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $FileDB

                )
        {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_FileDB = $FileDB;
        }
```

and

```
$this->_FileDB->copyFile($_oldPath,$_NewPath);
```

and still no file copied...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cp()` function of class `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File`

> vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Io/File.php

```
protected $_fileSystem;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $filesystemIo,
    ...
) {
    $this->filesystemIo = $filesystemIo;
}
 ...

$filePath  = '/var/www/html/var/import/order_status.csv'
$$copyFileFullPath  = '/var/www/html/var/import/readfiles/order_status.csv'

$filePath = $this->_fileSystemIo->cp($filePath, $copyFileFullPath);

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. For DB storage.
`Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database`

```
public function copyFile($oldName, $newName)
{
    if ($this->checkDbUsage()) {
        $this->getStorageDatabaseModel()->copyFile(
            $this->_removeAbsPathFromFileName($oldName),
            $this->_removeAbsPathFromFileName($newName)
        );
    }
}
```

It basically calls the `copyFile()` of this class `\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Storage\Database` which in turn call this class `Magento\MediaStorage\Model\ResourceModel\File\Storage\Database`.

Comment: thanks for your answer : I get a Zend_Db_Statement_Exception exception (cf. my edit)

Comment: That function needs only 2 params. `copyFile($oldFilePath, $newFilePath)`. Why you are sending 4 params? Open the file and check the function.

Comment: I made the correction and get a 'magentoDB.media_storage_file_storage does not exist

Comment: any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: Let me  try it. Will post after checking.

Comment: Are you using db storage or file storage ?

Comment: Check now. You should use DB storage to use the same.

Comment: the function is called, but does not enter if section $this->checkDbUsage() == false

Comment: Yes because you should use DB STORAGE..not file storage.

Comment: ok.. you are talking about the backend system configuration regarding media storage. The filecopy is for the files uploaded by costumers for a product custom option file (I am adapting this option for my needs) In my previous Magento1.9 system, i was using file storage. If I use on the new magento2 system to DB storage, does it means the files will be stored in database? each uploaded file being several Mo, the DB will reach the Go soon.. What is the best solution according to you?

Comment: I am not sure. But the function you were using in M1.9 that is as same as this one. If you open `Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->copyFile()` this function (its M1.9) you will see both are same function. In magento 1.9 also its for db. There also it has this piece of code `$this->checkDbUsage()`. But Yes you cant store files in db. Thats bad.

Comment: therefore, why not simply use $this->_iofile->cp($_QuoteFullPath,$_OrderFullPath); ?